# Facebook Graph API Searching on Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I use the following to code to retrieve data from Facebook Graph API and it works.

```
GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
                        , "/me"
                        , new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                showToast(response.toString());
                                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_textview)).setText(response.toString());
                            }
                        }).executeAsync();
```

However, when I use the following search query which works in Graph API Explorer it doesn't work anymore.

```
GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
                        , "/search?q=coffee&type=place"
                        , new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                showToast(response.toString());
                                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_textview)).setText(response.toString());
                            }
                        }).executeAsync();
```

The error json is below.

```
Response:responseCode:400,
graphObject:null,
error:{  
   HttpStatus:400,
   errorCode:100,
   errorType:GraphMethodException,
   errorMessage:   Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
}
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? why are you using this graph api node?

Comment: I'm trying to search places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation. You are doing it the wrong way.

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "...?fields={fieldname_of_type_Location}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync()
```

**OR**

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
  accessToken,
  "/search",
  new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
      // Insert your code here
    }
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("type", "place");
parameters.putString("center", "53,27");
parameters.putString("distance", "30000");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

In field you can use country, longitude, latitude , cite etc. Here is [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/)

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: I'm trying to do like this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

Comment: try this answer if this doesn't work then let me know. But you should make sure to add valid query

Comment: how can I use that if I want to search for "coffee".

Comment: I have edited my answer. let me know if it doesn't work